# Eval returns false even tough values are equal

Tags: vbscript

```
sCResult = Eval(Trim(760.27 + 64.56 = 824.83))

Select Case sCResult
Case False
    MsgBox("This is False ")
Case True
    MsgBox("This is True ")
Case Else
    MsgBox("This is Error ")
End Select
```

Comment: If you are using `EVal()` the argument should be a string. Should change line to `sCResult = Eval(Trim(“760.27 + 64.56 = 824.83”))`.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation does not return true because the elements of the equation are floating point numbers which cannot be represented exactly. 760.27 may be converted to 760.270000000001 once stored in a floating point register.

This is why 760.27 + 64.56 = 824.83 is false.

Some floating point values can be represented exactly like 0.5 or 0.25.

This is why 760.75 + 64.75 = 825.5 is true.

What you can do is convert your numbers to a variant of subtype currency and your equation will be true:

CCur(760.27) + CCur(64.56) = CCur(824.83)

Comment: The `trim` is completely pointless with numbers. There will NEVER be spaces in it.

Comment: I agree. `Eval` and `Trim` are not relevant here.

Comment: You don't need to convert each number individually. `CCur(760.27 + 64.56) = CCur(824.83)` would suffice. You could also use `Round(<expr>, 2)` instead of `CCur(<expr>)`.

Comment: You can also do ((760.27 + 64.56) - 824.83) < 0.000001.

Comment: I am getting 760.75 + 64.75 = 825.5 as a string, So I am doing trim for any spaces. Is there any way we can do this without breaking up the string as individual fields ?